# Why does vim create a new file when opening an existing file?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, linux, linux-arch

First and foremost, I'm using Arch Linux. I have a file `dir/data.tex`.

I execute this command in terminal (when in the `dir` directory)

```
$ vim data.tex
```

I get the following output:

```
"indent" [New File]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Upon pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, Vim opens up an empty file!

Here is what my `.vimrc` looks like in my home directory `~/.vimrc`

```
n indent on
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That line:

```
n indent on
```

means "open the file called `indent` that is at the root of the working directory". Basically, you tell Vim to do something silly and… it does just that.

It should be:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Be more careful about what you copy and paste.